# How do you get headers as the output of flex and bison?

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

So, I'm making a giant program which uses a *flex* and *bison* parser to read a config file.

I need to include the output of the parser in my main.cpp program.

Using...

```
%output "config.cc"
%defines "config.h"
```

...just adds errors for "unidentified string". Other options haven't worked too well either. Any idea why this isn't working?

Here's my lexer and bison file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
#include "Monopoly.h"
using namespace std;
extern int yylex();
extern void yyerror(char*);
Monopoly game;
void yyerror(const char *str)
{
        fprintf(stderr,"error: %s\n",str);
}


%}

%token LTOKEN INTEGER LOCATIONWORD WORD GTOKEN CURRENCYTOKEN JAILFINETOKEN STARTINGMONEYTOKEN RTOKEN COSTTOKEN RENTTOKEN FILEPATHTOKEN OBJEXTENSION MODELTOKEN TAXTOKEN PERCENTSIGN


%union{
  std::string *str;
  int number;
}
%token <number> INTEGER
%token <str> WORD


%%
commands: /* empty */
        | command commands
        ;

command:
        currency_set
        |
        location_set
        |
        startingMoney_set
        |
        jailFine_set
        |
        route_add
        |
        cost_set
        |
        rent_set
        |
        filepath_found
        |
        tax_set
        ;
filepath_found:MODELTOKEN LTOKEN INTEGER FILEPATHTOKEN WORD OBJEXTENSION
        {
            printf(" File %s HAS BEEN IMPORTED for location number %d \n",$5,$3 );
        }

rent_set:RENTTOKEN LTOKEN INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER   
        {
            printf("rent for house no 4 is %d \n",$7);
        } 
cost_set:COSTTOKEN LTOKEN INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER
        {
            printf("prices set to %d\n",$10 );
        }
currency_set:CURRENCYTOKEN WORD
            {
                
                game.currency=($2);
                printf("Currency set to %s",game.currency->c_str());
            }
            
location_set:
            LOCATIONWORD LTOKEN INTEGER WORD GTOKEN INTEGER
            {
            printf("location number %d  set to  %s in froup number %d",$3,$4,$6);
            }
startingMoney_set:
            STARTINGMONEYTOKEN INTEGER
            {
            printf("starting money set to %d \n",$2 );
            }
jailFine_set:
            JAILFINETOKEN INTEGER
            {
                printf("jailfine set to %d\n",$2);
            }

route_add:
            RTOKEN LTOKEN INTEGER LTOKEN INTEGER
            {
                printf("Route set up between location no %d and %d\n",$3,$5);
            }

tax_set:
        TAXTOKEN INTEGER PERCENTSIGN INTEGER
        {
            printf("tax set to %d percent\n",$2 );
        }


%%


int yywrap()
{
        return 1;
} 
extern FILE * yyin;

int main()
{
    yyin=fopen("config.txt","r");
    yyparse();
    
    
    string json="{ \"hello\" : \"world\"} ";
    rapidjson::Document d;
    d.Parse<0>(json.c_str());
    
    printf("%s\n", d["hello"].GetString());
    return 1;
} 


%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "bisoner.tab.h"
using namespace std;
%}
%%
"Tax"                       return TAXTOKEN;
"rent"                      return RENTTOKEN;
"cost"                      return COSTTOKEN;
"route"                     return RTOKEN;
"Currency"                  return CURRENCYTOKEN;
"StartingMoney"             return STARTINGMONEYTOKEN;
"JailFine"                  return JAILFINETOKEN;
"location"                  return LOCATIONWORD;
"@l"                        return LTOKEN;
"@g"                        return GTOKEN;
"model"                     return MODELTOKEN;
"#"[a-zA-Z0-9.-_= ]+            printf("comment ignored\n");
[0-9]+                      yylval.number=atoi(yytext);return INTEGER;
[a-zA-Z]+                   yylval.str=new string(yytext);return WORD;
"./"([[a-zA-Z0-9]+"/"]*)?               return FILEPATHTOKEN;
".obj"                      return OBJEXTENSION;
"%"                         return PERCENTSIGN;

%%
```

How can I get *flex* and *bison* to generate header files in addition to the normal source output?

Comment: Dp you implement main as part of bison/flex or it is separate from this?

Comment: Separate. main contains a bunch of opengl code, actually.

Comment: Then you have obvious mistake with main in bison/flex. I'll try to write sample C++ implementation if I have time. I do really suggest you to rewrite it without main and as C++ code.

Comment: I don't see any `%option` declarations anywhere in that file, so either they are imaginary or they are in some other file. Three things: `flex` and `bison` have different ways of declaring output filenames. Both of them have command-line options (but they are also slightly different). You need to make sure you have the same version of `flex` and `bison` as the documentation you are reading. Finally, in one of my answers to one of your questions, I provided working flex and bison files with functioning file declarations (but for the latest version of both utilities).

Answer (score 3):

Proper flex/bison setup in a modern C++ project is a major PITA, as the examples are rather poor quality and the generated code encourages outdated practices, such as non-reentrant code and global variables. That was ok in the '80, not 2014.

Try adapting my example I made few weeks ago. The setup is super-straightforward, as it encapsulates Flex lexer and Bison parser in a separate class (called Interpreter) in separate namespace. It is reentrant and compatible with good, old C++03.

https://github.com/ezaquarii/bison-flex-cpp-example

The only tricky part is to refactor class names to suit your needs. Once you compile it you can start working on *.y and *.l files to implement your interesting stuff, without fighting Bison/Flex setup idiosyncrasies. Enjoy!

Comment: Note: https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cr4bd/flex-manual/Code_002dLevel-And-API-Options.html#Code_002dLevel-And-API-Options] describes a bunch of options (for flex, anyways) that can mitigate a lot of the old weirdness; e.g. `%option reentrant`, `%option prefix`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with was to compile the files together. Simply declare the yyparse() function  as extern in the other cpp files, and any other variables. I'll attach my makefile below

```
CFLAGS=-ll
CC=g++
all:example2
example2: main.cpp lex.yy.c bisoner.tab.c
    $(CC) main.cpp lex.yy.c bisoner.tab.c Player.cpp Location.cpp Monopoly.cpp -o example2 -ll
bisoner.tab.c:bisoner.y
    bison -d bisoner.y
lex.yy.c:lexer.l 
    lex lexer.l

clean:
    rm -rf *o example2
```

Answer (score 0):

[For *flex*](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Options-for-Specifying-Filenames.html#Options-for-Specifying-Filenames), at least, you can either:

- Specify `--header-file=filename.h` on the command line, or
- Specify `%option header-file="filename.h"` in the spec file. The equal sign and quotes are important.

Either of those will generate *filename.h* which contains a copy of all the definitions and declarations that appear at the top of the generated source file.

Example:

```
// mylexer.l
%option header-file="mylexer.h"
%{
   ...
%}
%%
   ...
%%
```

Comment: Both flex and bison conform to the usual convention for command-line tools; the `--help` command-line option documents command-line usage. The [bison manual is here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/); if the Windows package isn't broken, it should also be somewhere on your machine

Comment: @rici I don't understand, sorry. I've got bison and flex installed and running with no issues, and I'm not having any issues with command line usage. I also know where to find the bison manual. I just haven't got to the point in my project yet where I'm focused on bison, so I left a placeholder in my answer until I get the hang of bison and can fill in those details. I don't have any questions or issues regarding either of them. I just found this question when I was looking for the same info, and since I didn't find the answer here, I decided to share the solution I found.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Well; I'm sure I'm not causing any planes to crash by leaving a placeholder here. This isn't exactly a hot topic. :)